# How to run a cmd in Windows with Admin priviledges in Salt

Tags: salt-stack

I have a simple system that is managed by Saltstack. The minions are Windows Server 2016 machines. I would like to run some command with Admin privileges. How would I achieve that in the .sls for the minion?

```
run-my-cmd:
  cmd.run:
     - cwd: C:\temp\
     - bg: True
     - name: 'some command'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the command using Runas

C:\Users\abcxyz>Runas /profile /user:Administrator "your command"

Answer (score 0):

As this is the top hit on google and the accepted answer did not work for me.

i use this command from here [How to execute a powershell command as user XYZ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792078/how-to-execute-a-powershell-command-as-user-xyz):

```
salt '<minion>' cmd.run '<your command>' runas=Administrator shell=powershell
```

note: it's important to have `shell=powershell` as it does not work with `cmd` only.