# How to execute a powershell command as user XYZ?

Tags: powershell, salt-stack

I am trying to execute a PowerShell script on a salt-minion windows server from a salt master Linux server.

I am sending the command like this:

```
salt My-server cmd.run "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\my_script.ps1" shell=powershell
```

This works but I need to execute this script as a specific user.

I have tried all of the following:

```
salt My-server cmd.run "start powershell -credential "XYZ" C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\my_script.ps1"

salt My-server cmd.run "runas/user:XYZ "powershell.exe C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\my_script.ps1" 

salt My-server cmd.run "runas/user:XYZ C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\my_script.ps1" shell=powershell
```

But all of them either fail to run the script or don't have the desired effect.

I don't know much about PowerShell but I know how to do the same in Linux bash:

```
su -c "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\my_script.ps1" XYZ
```

I am aware that's not a valid Linux path but you see the point.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `runas` option for `cmd.run`? Such as:

```sh
salt My-server cmd.run "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\my_script.ps1" runas=XYZ shell=powershell
```

The documentation seems to imply that `password=` argument may be required, too:

```
runas (str) -- Specify an alternate user to run the command. The default
behavior is to run as the user under which Salt is running. If running on 
a Windows minion you must also use the password argument, and the target 
user account must be in the Administrators group.
```

### Documentation references:

- https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.powershell (for `cmd.run` with the `runas` option via execution module, with `shell=powershell`, which also includes the added information around needing `password=` against Windows minions)
- https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run (for `cmd.run` with the `runas` option in `states`)